# How to save my data to an array with 2 indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working on some stock application where you can have more than one stock and at the same time, you can have one item in 2 or more different stocks. So there is the problem. I'm saving my items data to arrays like this one

```
 $cart[$data->resource_id] = array
 (
 'resID' => $data->resource_id,
 'stoID' => $data->stock_id,
 'stoName' => $data->sto_name,
 'resName' => $data->res_name,
 'actQuantity' => $data->quantity,
 'minimum' => $data->minimum,
 'quantity' => $quant
 );
```

but what I need to do now is to save my data to an array with something with 2 indexes (?). First index - resource_id, second stock_id - so I know with item it is and on with stock it is. So I think something like this

```
 $cart[$data->resource_id, $data->stock_id] = array
 (
 'resID' => $data->resource_id,
 'stoID' => $data->stock_id,
 'stoName' => $data->sto_name,
 'resName' => $data->res_name,
 'actQuantity' => $data->quantity,
 'minimum' => $data->minimum,
 'quantity' => $quant
 );
```

but it's obviously not the correct code.

How to do this?

Comment: `$cart[$data->resource_id][$data->stock_id] =`

Comment: `$MyArray[$MainArrayIndex][$SubArrayIndex]`

Comment: Why exactly do you "need" that? Are you sure that this is a good data structure? Within your cart elements, you already have both indices at hand

Answer (score 0):

You select it by `$cart[$data->resource_id][$data->stock_id]`, so without comma.
To set the value you can type

```
$cart[$data->resource_id][$data->stock_id] = [
   'stoName' => $data->sto_name,
   'resName' => $data->res_name
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create array like below.

```
$cart[$data->resource_id] = [ 
    $data->stock_id => [

        'resID' => $data->resource_id,
        'stoID' => $data->stock_id,
        'stoName' => $data->sto_name,
        'resName' => $data->res_name,
        'actQuantity' => $data->quantity,
        'minimum' => $data->minimum,
        'quantity' => $quant
    ] 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP do not support multi dimensional arrays, at least not as you want.

To do multi dimensional arrays on PHP, you must use nested arrays:

```
$a = [
    "keyA" => [
        "keyB" => 'somedata';
    ]
]
```

So you need to initialize the array:

```
$cart = [];

$cart[$data->resource_id] = []; // Do this just in the first time that you insert something inside that `resource_id`, otherwise you will resetting the array.

$cart[$data->resource_id][$data->stock_id] = [
    //... your data here ...
]
```

For example, imagine that you want to get this data:

```
$input = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo' ],
    [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar' ],
    [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 3, 'name' => 'biz' ],
]
```

And organize it by `id` and `stock_id`.

You should do a script like this:

```
$output =  [];

foreach ($input as $item) {
    if (!array_key_exists($item['id'], $output)) {
        $output[$item['id']] = []; // Initializing the 2nd level array
    }

    $output[$item['id']][$item['stock_id']] = $item;
}
```

The `$output` array will look look like this:

```
[
    1 => [
        1 => [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo' ],
        2 => [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar' ],
        3 => [ 'id' => 1, 'stock_id' => 3, 'name' => 'biz' ],
    ]
]
```

So you can access the data like this:

```
echo $output[1][3]['name']
// Will output `biz`
```